# elixir string to method arguments in macro

Tags: macros, elixir

I'm messing around with macros in elixir purely for fun and not profit :). So I have a comma separated string and I want to dynamically create a function with that list as arguments i.e.

```
defmacro  __using__(opts) do
  args = "a,b,c"
  quote do
    def test(unquote(args)) do
      IO.inspect("#{a},#{b},#{c}")
    end
  end
end
```

The problem I have is that the method created is: `test("1,2,3")` and not `test(1,2,3)` for obvious reasons. So how do I convert a string into a method argument?

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way but one way to convert `"a,b,c"` to something that can be injected into `def`'s argument list would be to use `Code.string_to_quoted!/1` and `unquote_splicing`:

```
defmacro  __using__(_opts) do
  args = "a,b,c"
  args = Code.string_to_quoted!("[#{args}]")
  quote do
    def test(unquote_splicing(args)) do
      IO.inspect(unquote(args))
    end
  end
end
```

Note that due to hygiene, you'll have to use `args` to access the variables and you cannot directly access `a`, `b`, or `c` inside the def.

Full Example:

```
defmodule Macros do
  defmacro  __using__(_opts) do
    args = "a,b,c"
    args = Code.string_to_quoted!("[#{args}]")
    quote do
      def test(unquote_splicing(args)) do
        IO.inspect(unquote(args))
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Main do
  use Macros

  def main do
    test("a", "b", "c")
    test(1, 2, 3)
  end
end

Main.main
```

Output:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
[1, 2, 3]
```